# How do I convert an existing Google account to G Suite?

Tags: google-account, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I have an existing account using an e-mail at a domain I control (e.g., `orome@my-domain.com`) and would like to convert that account to a G Suite account. I'm unclear on the correct steps to do that while still preserving the data and credentials associated with my `orome@my-domain.com` account. Is there a way to accomplish this, and if so what are the steps involved?

Comment: Please read [Add users who have existing Google Accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7044710?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén: So it's (1) create a G Suite account using an admin address for `my-domain.com` and then (2) "invite" `orome@my-domain.com` to transfer their (my) account (option 1 in the [linked instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7044710?hl=en)) which will result in my existing Google account being converted (with all content) to a G Suite account. Correct?

Comment: I suggest you to ask to G Suite support because it's not clear to me that doing that will  the preserve "the data and credentials"